# How do I get printer marks in Inskscape 0.92?

Tags: print-design, inkscape, crop, bleed

Yeah, as the title says - how can I get printer marks in inkscape 0.92?

Found this https://itstillworks.com/12597955/how-to-add-bleed-marks-to-inkscape which says:

> Click the "Extensions" menu, hover over "Render" and select the "Printing Marks..." option to open the Printing Marks window.
>
> Ensure the check boxes labeled "Crop Marks" and "Bleed Marks" are checked.

But I don't have such a menu in Inskscape 0.92, Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The menus have changed a bit in 0.92, but the extension is still there.

Click *Extensions > Render > Layout > Printing marks*

[image]

Comment: In 1.3.1, they have seemingly changed again, because these are now at: Extensions > Document > Layout > Printing marks.

Answer (score 1):

The question was about 0.92, but in 1.3 the menu changed again.

*Printing marks* in this version are placed at *Extensions > Document > Layout > Printing marks*.

Hope it can help someone.